# how not to disturb the data being reflected while changing from table-old Vizualization to Just Table.. ?(Table migration)

Tags: grafana, influxdb, grafana-dashboard

How not to disturb data while migrating to table panel [data is getting disturbed while migrating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAp43.png)

i tried migrating but the data which was being visible gets disturbed and it gets difficult to rearrange or get back the old data